# Port 8000, PID 4, not able to kill, taskill /f /pid 4, Access Denied

Tags: python, windows, simplehttpserver, taskkill

I am not able to kill process bound to 8000 port, due to which I am not able to start HTTP server. This is in reference to question
 [Start HTTP/HTTPS server, python -m SimpleHTTPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955988/start-http-https-server-python-m-simplehttpserver/25956220#25956220)

```
C:\>taskkill /f /pid 4
ERROR: The process with PID 4 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

Even killing by below is not working which I found somewhere.

```
C:\>taskkill /f /s localhost /pid 4
ERROR: The process with PID 4 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access Denied.
```

PID 4 is system process, what might be running on there, how do I stop it, why are other ports is a similar fashion listening.

```
C:\>netstat -ab

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            garg10may-PC:0         LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            garg10may-PC:0         LISTENING
 [vmware-hostd.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            garg10may-PC:0         LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:902            garg10may-PC:0         LISTENING
 [vmware-authd.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:912            garg10may-PC:0         LISTENING
 [vmware-authd.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           garg10may-PC:0         LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
```

Comment: Run your command prompt as administrator.

Comment: Yes, logined as administrator only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) the `http.server` module can also be invoked directly using the `-m` switch of the interpreter with a port number argument. Similar to the previous example, this serves the files relative to the current directory.

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

In case your port 8000 is already is being used just change it to another no.

```
python -m http.server 5000
```

It's not a good idea to arbitrarily just kill processes and more over system processes.

Answer (score 9):

if you're in Windows this might help you, the port 80 is usually being used by this service: "World Wide Web Publishing Service", open "Services" in the Control Panel and stop it

Comment: Also known as Web Deployment Services

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this - there is a reason why you are not able to kill it, because you didn't start it. Instead pass another port number:

For Python 3:

```
python -m http.server 8080
```

For Python 2:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

Comment: Yes able to start on another port, but still curious what might be running on that port and it that case also I should be able to kill that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, just check it is not IIS.
(yes some of us still have it installed locally for some reason)

Start > IIS > Right click on your IIS and stop

It can happen when you restart your computer maybe because of windows updates.